# Effort Entity Framework Sequence contains not matching elements

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, effort

So I've been trying to setup Effort and am not having much success.  Looking on their site and people's comments it looks pretty straightforward.

I started small because I just wanted to test if it works.  The error I get is
"Sequence contains no matching element"

I've added a constructor like so to the dbcontext.

```
public ApplicationDbContext(DbConnection connection) 
        : base(connection, true)
    {
    }
```

My setup like so for my test

```
var connection = Effort.DbConnectionFactory.CreateTransient();
var context = new ApplicationDbContext(connection );
```

Just a test to see if it works

```
context.Set<MyType>().Add(new MyType() {Description = "test"});
```

Class for MyType

```
public class MyType
    {
        [Key]
        public byte Id { get; set; }

        [Required, MaxLength(50)]
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

I have also tried this with the createpersistent.  Same result.

I am using ef6 code first, mvc 5, .net 462.

Comment: man i can't type today and it won't let me change the question go figure..

Comment: Did you see [this?](https://github.com/tamasflamich/effort/issues/10) Seems to be an issue with datatype annotations.

Comment: did you save your changes made in the context into your database? what does your IQueryable look like?

Comment: As @C.Helling, said, it may be caused by attributes. Try to change `MaxLength` to `StringLength`

Comment: @C.Helling that was one of the first pages I looked at with my search :P

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov It turned out being the column(typename) on one of my other models

Comment: @user892381 Well, the link indicated that it seemed to be an issue with datatype annotations, that certain ones worked with EF and others didn't (e.g. date vs datetime, boolean vs bit, etc). Apparently, yours was caused by the XML datatype annotation. I was guessing in the direction I thought the issue was, but you can see why other people (like me) weren't able to debug your specific issue based on the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem I had another data model with a property containing the following annotation.  It didn't like it.  Commented it out and it worked.

[Column(TypeName = "XML")]